# Unable to get button ID in Chrome with AutoHotKey

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, autohotkey

I got used to AHK to automate some repetitive tasks i'm doing on web. I'm trying to study more about this beautiful program and extend it to do more complex tasks in future. Now, what I try to make him do and can't make it, is to make him get the ID of one single button on webpage and use command `.click()` on it, making after to popup an alert box.

```
<button id="demo" type="button" onclick="alert('Hello world!')">Click Me!</button>
```

This is my .ahk code:

```
^p::
wb = WBGet()
wb.document.getElementById( "demo").click()

return
```

I was wondering if maybe someday chrome would be able to work with Autohotkey? I've tried numerous ways for it to work but since I think Chrome doesnt use COM there's no way for autohotkey to detect it. I think Autohotkey is a wonderful program but the only downside it can only automate IE...

Answer (score 0):

First you need to make sure function "wbget()" written for chrome, as far as I know "wbget()" is written for IE.